# Patch unwanted column attribute

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I have an object

```
class Summary():
    __tablename__ = 'employeenames'
    name= Column('employeeName', String(128, collation='utf8_bin'))
    date = Column('dateJoined', Date)
```

I want to patch Summary with a mock object

```
class Summary():
    __tablename__ = 'employeenames'
    name= Column('employeeName', String)
    date = Column('dateJoined', Date)
```

or just patch name the field to `name= Column('employeeName', String)`

The reason I'm doing this is that I'm doing my tests in sqlite and some queries that are only for Mysql are interfering with my tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be difficult to mock the column.  However you could instead [conditionally compile](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/compiler.html#changing-compilation-of-types) the `String` type for Sqlite, removing the collation.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.types import String


@compiles(String, 'sqlite')
def compile_varchar(element, compiler, **kw):
    type_expression = kw['type_expression']
    type_expression.type.collation = None
    return compiler.visit_VARCHAR(element, **kw)


Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Summary(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employeenames'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column('employeeName', sa.String(128, collation='utf8_bin'))
    date = sa.Column('dateJoined', sa.Date)


urls = ['mysql:///test', 'sqlite://']
for url in urls:
    engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=True, future=True)
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This script produces the expected output for MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employeenames (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `employeeName` VARCHAR(128) COLLATE utf8_bin, 
    `dateJoined` DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

but removes the collation for Sqlite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employeenames (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "employeeName" VARCHAR(128), 
    "dateJoined" DATE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```